# Describing lifecycle of fragments with a real practical example

Tags: android, android-fragments

[I have kept this video tutorial as reference ---- Click here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdpmeT4Q1hk)

Device:: Mobile

Initial-State :: Portrait Mode

When we launch a application this is the series of functions called

`onAttach()` ---> `onCreate()` ---> `onCreateview()` ---> `onActivityCreated()` ---> `onStart()` ---> `onResume()`

Now i switch to :: Landscape Mode

these are the series of functions called

`onPause()` -- in between here SAVE_INSTANCE_STATE ---> `onStop()` ---> `onDestroyView()` ---> `onDestroy()` ---> `onDetach()`

If i exit the application

`onPause()` ---> `onStop()` ---> `onDestroyView()` ---> `onDestroy()` ---> `onDetach()`

My Questions::

- Am i correct in my explanation ?
- If i am wrong where can i correct this ?
- I am not understanding savedInstancestate part ..... is it like
  android preserves the views to display so that i can hold on when the
  screen is being flipped even after `onDetach()` occurs?
- I never saw mentioning of `savedinstancestate` in [fragments life
  cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) ... then how can it come here ?

Please go easy on answers i am a newbie

Comment: I never saw mentioning of savedinstancestate in fragments life cycle ... then how can it come here ? what do you mean by this? have you check the code snippet of TitlesFragment in the same link?

Comment: I mean the video tutorial ... link ... i posted ... speaker gives a practical explanation of life-cycle execution .... i clearly see it pop up there .... particularly when orientation of screen is flipped .... please check the video tutorial link  Or is it just not necessay .... then even after onDetach ... how come i see the fragments on the screen :)

Comment: you need to check the docs its clearly explained

Comment: But when we flip the screen is onPause() ---> onStop() ---> onDestroyView() ---> onDestroy() ---> onDetach() executed ? ..... if so how is the state of the screen retained ?

Comment: on Home key press before onPause(), onsavedinstancestate method executed in Fragment

Comment: @smriti3 `@Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
   outState.putString("key1", value);
  }` then   `if( savedInstanceState!=null)
     {
        
      value = savedInstanceState.getString("key1");` in   `@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K ...........so is that the reason we are able to retain the state on flipping screen and execution of onPause() ---> onStop() ---> onDestroyView() ---> onDestroy() ---> onDetach()

Comment: @smriti3 pls check the code snippets in the docs it is there

Comment: @smriti3 remember fragment is hosted by a activity. when orientation changes activity is destroyed and recreated. put a log statemetn in your fragment lifecycle methods and check yourself. the values are restored .http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: @ Raghunandan ..... Yes ... Now i understand ....when orientation changes activity is destroyed and recreated .... and since life-cycle of fragments is directly proportional to hosted life cycle of activity .... Hence the saved instance state .... yes now i got it .... Thanks !